# Blank screen and necessary scroll event to get values in a store with few records in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Working with Sencha touch application, I am having the next problem and I think is a bug from time ago..

When the user is filtering from a searchfield and the values found are (for instance) 1 or 2 records, the ipad screen sometimes does not appear items, it appears blank screen and it is necessary a light scroll movement to see the values.

Anyone know this bug and I have a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of ST?

Comment: It is happening in 2.4.1 and 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, in order to reproduce the problem you have to open a long, paged list, then swipe down until you are at least on the second page, then call `store.setFilter(...)` and `store.load()` on the list's store.

The calls to setFilter and load are not resetting the page number to 1, so you are asking for the second (or third) page of the searched data.

If your server side works like mine, you'll get an empty result set, with a total number of 1 or 2 records.

You can search by yourself for the problem, debugging from Chrome dev tools (or whatever suits you best), and checking the start, limit and page parameters included in the request for data issued by the "incriminated" store load.

One possible, simple solution, is to call `store.loadPage(1)` instead of `load`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is not a problem with the server, it looks like a problem with the rendering of the view, for this reason I think is a bug with the Sencha Touch framework, but it is complicated to test because the behavior is randomly and it not happening always.

Comment: Did you check the Ajax traffic? If you are sure it's not about the store, you can try to insert a view.getScroller().scroller.scrollTo(0) AFTER the load. (by memory). Btw, are you on 4.2.2 or what?

Comment: I am implementing this `this.getListMaterials().getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, 0);` and using Sencha Touch 2.4.1 but it is happening also in the latest version.